# What is difference between MySQL cursor and while loop

Tags: mysql

How cursor is different from while loop. Execution wise which is faster and safe in case of failure.

Answer (score 1):

Cursor is kind of pointer variable to a table row, where you loop over the rows by using the loop. So, answering to your question which is faster, then i would say loop and cursor are two different things cursor is a variable and loop is a iterator, and without loop you can't use the cursor.

Also, i suggest if possible you can use recursive CTE, to perform the operation that you are doing via cursor.